# SQL Server Management Studio - how to specify UTF-8 parameter to stored procedure arguments?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which searches by text passed by a parameter. I noticed that if the text is not in English (i.e. Hebrew, Arabic), the query finishes without returning any rows. I am sure there is data to be found

I dont know which SQL server is being used : it is whatever is provided by GoDaddy on shared Windows hosting plan.

The thing is, I have a asp.net site which can search and fetch the data from this column encoded as UTF-8. The path which does not work is the MS SQL Management Studio. Even when I manually run same stored procedures which work from inside asp.net - they dont manage to find non English characters. The parameters I pass to the query are prefixed by N qualifier.

Comment: make sure your input is NVARCHAR not VARCHAR.

Comment: Side note: SQL Server (at least before 2017) doesn't support UTF-8 - it only supports UCS-2 ("utf-16") with a 2-byte-per-character setup.

Comment: Your question is too broad to me, Please provide more details, like your SP code, sample data, expected results and ... -HTH ;).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the N character like the sample :

```
Select * from students where name like N'%بیژن%'
```

and as mentioned in the comment the column data type should be Nvarchar.